# Were Al Capone's family calling him Phonse?

Tags: realism, capone

In the 2020 film *Capone*, Al Capone's family always call him Phonse. His real name was Alphonse Capone (I didn't write his middle name). But everyone knew him by the name Al. So were his family really calling him Phonse?

Comment: I can't find any evidence of this. Even the book "*Uncle Al Capone*" only mentions him being called 'Al' or 'Alphonse' by his family.

Comment: This appears to be an invention of the makers. I can't find any reference to him being "fonz" or "fons" or "fonzo" (the original name of the film) or "phonse" or "phonso" before 2018, when they announced the film.